# Disable/Enable inputText with selectBooleanCheckbox in Primefaces

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

Hey trying to disable/enable inputText based on a change event when a selectBooleanCheckbox is selected/unselected. Currently though, regardless of what whether or not the checkbox is selected, the inputText will always be disabled. Do I need to instead attach a listener to the checkbox? It seems in this case the inputText is never getting re-rendered.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Additional Time: " />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dialogView.additionalTime}" ajax="true" event="change" update="hour"/>    
</div>

<div>
    <p:outputLabel for="hour" value="Hour:" />
    <p:inputText id="hour" value="#{dialogView.hour}" disabled="#{!dialogView.additionalTime}" label="Hour" />      
</div>
```

Comment: @Ravi is right, where did you read `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dialogView.additionalTime}" ajax="true" event="change" update="hour"/>` is supported? Please stop using that tutorial and use the PF showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Tested on PrimFaces 6.0,6.1 and 6.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <div>
            <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Additional Time: " />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dialogView.additionalTime}">
                <p:ajax update="hour"></p:ajax>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p:outputLabel for="hour" value="Hour:" />
            <p:inputText id="hour" value="#{dialogView.hour}" disabled="#{!dialogView.additionalTime}" label="Hour" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```